# How to implement thread library?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, linux-kernel

Is writing a code for implementing the thread library a part of kernel code ?
Is the function implementation of pthread_create() et al a part of kernel ?

Answer (score 5):

In Linux, `pthread_create()` et al. is implemented as part of the glibc project.  It uses the (non-portable, Linux-specific) syscall `clone()`.  (Linux's `fork()` is also implemented in terms of `clone()`).  Some of the BSDs also have similar syscall called `rfork()`.

My understanding is that `clone()` or `rfork()` will both create a new process, but you can specify a flag that says, "use copy-on-write semantics to give this a different address space".  So, if you want `fork()`, you specify that flag, but if you want to create a thread, you don't, and you end up with a shared address space.

(edited to provide more detail)

Answer (score 3):

Threads are sometimes implemented purely in user space (then also called "green threads"), but typically in kernel space. The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computer_science)) explains it nicely.